# lxml doc.find returning None

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have this xml output, I want to extract few elements.

**Sample XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:2.0" message-id="101">
  <data>
    <bl1 xmlns="http://example.com/ns/xyz/xxx-op">
      <A>
        <B>
          <C>
            <D>
              <E>0.0.0.0</E>
              <F>1200</F>
              <C>
                <G>0</G>
                <H>0</H>
                <I>0</I>
                <J>0</J>
                <K>0</K>
                <L>0</L>
                <M>0</M>
                <N>0</N>
                <O>0</O>
                <P>0</P>
                <Q>0</Q>
                <R>0</R>
                <S>0</S>
                <T>0</T>
                <U>0</U>
                <V>0</V>
                <W>0</W>
                <X>0</X>
              </C>
              <Y>1.1.1.1</Y>
              <Z>IPv6</Z>
            </D>
          </C>
        </B>
      </A>
    </bl1>
  </data>
</rpc-reply>
```

I tried the following snippet

**Code**

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse("sample.xml")
print doc
memoryElem = doc.find('Y')
print memoryElem
print memoryElem.text        # element text
```

Somehow, this is not working. memoryElem is printing None.
Can you correct me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Your edit to the title was fine, but I rolled back because you removed vital code.

Answer (score 3):

Your target element is in the default namespace :

```
xmlns="http://example.com/ns/xyz/xxx-op"
```

You need to map a prefix to the default namespace URI, and use that prefix to reference element in the namespace :

```
ns = {'d': 'http://example.com/ns/xyz/xxx-op'}
memoryElem = doc.find('.//d:Y', ns)
print memoryElem.text
```

Comment: Why do you use `d` as the namespace prefix? Is this arbitrary?

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes, it is arbitrary, as long as it mapped to the correct namespace URI (my idea was 'd' for 'default')

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a namespace problem.

You could try [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open("sample.xml", "r").read(), features="xml")
yt = soup.find("Y").text
print(yt)
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
```